# Get index element in list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
  <li>Kelvin</li>
  <li>Jerry</li>
  <li>Adi</li>
  <li>Dani</li>
  <li>Olvin</li>
</ul>
```

How to get the index of the `<li>` element that contains "Jerry"?

I've tried to read these

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/
- http://api.jquery.com/index/

But can't find the answer :(
Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using jQuery's `.index` will give you the index of an element in the given elements:

```
var index = $('li').index($('li:contains("Jerry")'));
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]  

var index = $('li').index($('li:contains("Jerry")'); :(

Comment: Ah, sorry, fixed it. Missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat more efficiently:

```
var jerry = $('li:contains("Jerry")');
var jerry_index = jerry.siblings().index(jerry);
```

Comment: You'll have to change it to `jerry.parent().children().index(jerry);` though, since `.index` works on a set of elements.