# jQuery: How to determine the index of <li> element in an unordered list when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the index of the clicked li element in the unordered list. How to achieve this with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get index element in list with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630507/get-index-element-in-list-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul li').on('click', function(ev) {
   var index = $(this).index();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$( 'li' ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( this ).index()
} )
```

Answer (score 2):

this ?
http://api.jquery.com/index/

```
<head>
  <style>
div { background:yellow; margin:5px; }
span { color:red; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span>Click a div!</span>
<div>First div</div>
<div>Second div</div>
<div>Third div</div>
<script>
$("div").click(function () {
  // this is the dom element clicked
  var index = $("div").index(this);
  $("span").text("That was div index #" + index);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

*code from Jquery Api*

Comment: Sory for asking so simple question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The OP specifically asked about unordered list elements, not divs. -1, sorry.

Comment: That's the worst -1 ever! Regardless of the element(s) in question index() is still the correct method to use

Answer (score 0):

Just do this way:-

```
$('li').click(function() {
   alert($(this).index());
});
```